# Java- Multithreading does not increase performance on a multicore architecture

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, multicore

My multithreaded java application stagnates in performance after 8 threads. I tried running the same application concurrently, each instance in one thread. Each instance is build from the ground up / has its own object model, so there should be no sharing/syncing between the running instances.  My server is running with 4 CPUs x 8 cores (**32 physical cores**, 64logical cores with hyperthreading). The measurements are as follows:

- 1 Thread:   56m
- 4 Threads:  16m
- 8 Threads:  11m
- 16 Threads: 11m
- 32 Threads: 11m

I did some stress tests with 'stress-ng' and the performance was proportional to the thread count. 'Htop' also shows that the used cpus correlate with the specified thread count (so, specifying 16 threads will lead to 16 cores run at 100%). I also checked that my app didn't have nested threads that may somehow be "blocking" the cores.
What are possible reasons for the performance stagnation? What else can I check? My expectation is, that the performance should be proportional to the number of at least phyiscal cores.

This is the **entry point** of the application where multithreading is initialized:

```
    List<JsonNode> configs = configLoader.loadConfigs();
    System.out.println(">>>>> Starting to process "+configs.size()+" configs <<<<<<<");
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    CompletionService<TradingReport> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
    for(JsonNode config : configs) {
                 FileClientComponent fileClientComponent = DaggerFileClientComponent.builder()
                                        .configComponent(configComponent)
                                        .config(config)
                                        .build();
                 FileClient fileClient = fileClientComponent.initFileClient();
                 completionService.submit(fileClient);
    }
```

This is the relevant part from the **FileClient** class (implements Callable). From there one the input of a file is processed in the "dataForwarder":

```
@Override
public TradingReport call () throws InterruptedException {
    //process line by line
    Path path = Paths.get(referenceFile);
    //use "historical_data" resource folder when no path is specified
    if(!referenceFile.contains("/")) {
        path = Paths.get("src", "main", "resources", "historical_data", referenceFile);
    }

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path.toFile()))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !maxTestedBarsReached() && !Thread.interrupted()) {
            dataForwarder.processInput(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tradingReport;
}
```

Comment: Without understanding the intimate details of how your "multithreaded java application" is architected, designed and implemented, it is highly unlikely we can do more than offer general hints -- which is off-topic here.  SO is not a help/discussion forum.  Sorry.

Comment: Your performance is probably limited by I/O throughput or memory bandwidth.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I/O certainly is not a problem (I only read in a file which was very fast in tests) There are no write operations to disk, everything is handled in cache. What do you mean with memory bandwidth? Each running instance needs around 250mb according to Java VisualVM. 16GB RAM is installed in the server.

Comment: @JimGarrison I added the multithreading code

Comment: @terrenceH, "Memory bandwidth" refers to the speed with which the processors are able to move data in and out of the main memory system. There is only _one_ path to the main memory (a.k.a., "the system _bus_" or 
"memory bus"), and all of the CPUs must share it.

Comment: Alright, I do have 2 memory sticks connected in the server. Is it possible that they are connected to the wrong slot, so that all 4 CPUs work via the same memory bus. Wouldn't this mean that I'd need at least 4 memory sticks to feed each CPU with its own memory or at least allow it to use a separate memory bus?